# Windows Service Installation Path C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation-path

I have a Windows service I created and have the Setup project for it as well. Within that setup project I do have the installation path configured in the properties.

> [ProgramFilesFolder]Company123\ServicesMonitor

When I install the service through Visual Studio it works as intended, it installs to the correct place (C:\Program Files (x86)\Company123\ServicesMonitor). But when I install it using the Setup project's actual .exe or .msi found in the Setup project's release folder, it just installs the service to my root E:\ drive.

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go to projects release folder, go to Setup project release/debug folder and search for .exe or .msi file.

Comment: I am going to the Setup project's release folder. 

"But when I install it using the Setup project's actual .exe or .msi found in the Setup project's release folder"